# Angular / ngDraggable - parent DIV not scrolling when dragging object within

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, angular-material

Using ngDraggable/Angular Material and having problems dragging objects within the parent DIV container.

The DIV style has a defined height and an overflow-y of "scroll", and the data is a list of employees.

I was expecting the DIV tag to scroll as I dragged my object down the list, but the scrolling won't trigger.

Stuck for a solution.   Any help would be appreciated.   The following code snippet is a stripped down example of my code.

```css
.allEmployeeContainer {
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.employeeHolder{
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 10.5pt;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    margin:0px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="allEmployeeContainer">
    <div ng-repeat="employee in someCtrl.employees" style="padding:0px; margin:0px" >
        <div class="employeeHolder" layout="row" layout-wrap>
            <div style="width:100%; margin-top:10px;" layout="row" layout-wrap>
                <div flex="15">
                    <div class="drag-object" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="clip"></div><br />
                </div>
                <div flex>{{employee.firstName}}</div>
                <div flex>{{employee.lastName}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have two classes on your drag-object "person-icon" and "drag-object" are both of those suppose to be there and if so I would put them under one class for example: class="person-icon drag-object"?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i was trying to simply my actual code.  It was revised